# Is there a way to change the color of a line shape in an Office.js Excel add in?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I have tried the `shape.fill.setSolidColor("color");` method as well as `fill.setForegroundColor = 'color';` property. Neither of these seems to work and at times throw errors. Can a line shape be changed from its default blue color in excel add-ins? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Office JS world, Yes, the line shape color can be changed by `Shape.lineFormat` API. You may try the following sample code in the script lab

```
async function addStraightLine() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Shapes").shapes;
    const line = shapes.addLine(200, 50, 300, 150, Excel.ConnectorType.straight);
    line.lineFormat.color = "red";
    line.name = "StraightLine";
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

Reference document can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.shapelineformat?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: Thank you, don't think I would have ever found that elsewhere.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.shapelineformat?view=excel-js-preview here is the document that you could refer

Comment: Raymond is there a way to get the coordinates of the start/end points of a line in office.js? Thank You.

Comment: I just saw your message, i have replied your question, please review. thanks